# Array elements not showing in dynamically created div?

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to print array elements with html `li` element in a dynamically created `div` but no errors showing and neither array elements just an empty `div`.

What could be wrong?

Here is my code:

```
var fruitsName, fruitsLists, numFruits, i;

fruitsName = ["Mango", "Apple", "Banana", "Strawberry", "Blackberry", "Blueberry"];
numFruits = fruitsName.length;
fruitsLists = "<ul>";

for (i = 0; i < numFruits.length; i++)
{
    fruitsLists = "<li>" + fruitsName[i] + "</li>";
}
fruitsLists += "</ul>";
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.className = 'bookmarksHolder';
myDiv.id = 'randomItem';

document.getElementById('bookmarks_row').appendChild(myDiv);
document.getElementById('randomItem').innerHTML = fruitsLists;
```

Comment: i forgot to say im new to programming and stackoverflow as well, so i hope for no downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems: `numFruits` is already a length of array, so should be just `i < numFruits`. Second, in loop concatenate previous value with the current:

```
for (i = 0; i < numFruits; i++) {
  fruitsLists += "<li>" + fruitsName[i] + "</li>";
}
```

Complete sample:

```js
var fruitsName, fruitsLists, numFruits, i;

fruitsName = ["Mango", "Apple", "Banana", "Strawberry", "Blackberry", "Blueberry"];
numFruits = fruitsName.length;
fruitsLists = "<ul>";

for (i = 0; i < numFruits; i++) {
  fruitsLists += "<li>" + fruitsName[i] + "</li>";
}
fruitsLists += "</ul>";

var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.className = 'bookmarksHolder';
myDiv.id = 'randomItem';

document.getElementById('bookmarks_row').appendChild(myDiv);
document.getElementById('randomItem').innerHTML = fruitsLists;
```

```html
<div id="bookmarks_row"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning to `fruitsLists` in the loop, instead of appending. Also your array length is `numFruits`, so don't call `.length` of that. Change your loop to:

```
for (i = 0; i < numFruits; i++)
{
    fruitsLists += "<li>" + fruitsName[i] + "</li>";
}
```

You can also give the `ul` as innerHTML to the `div` prior to attaching the `div` to the DOM. This will invoke the rendering engine only once, instead of twice, and you wouldn't have to find the `div` by ID:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.className = 'bookmarksHolder';
myDiv.id = 'randomItem';
myDiv.innerHTML = fruitsLists;

document.getElementById('bookmarks_row').appendChild(myDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the loop, you need to concatenate instead of updating entire value otherwise `fruitsLists` includes the last generated HTML of li. Although update the for loop condition since `numFruits` holds the length.

```
for (i = 0; i < numFruits; i++)
//             ---------^^^---
{
    fruitsLists += "<li>" + fruitsName[i] + "</li>";
    //      ---^^^---
}
```